# Problems in adding android as platform in phonegap application

Tags: cordova

I downloaded the android SDK and extracted it to a directory.

I have set the system variables

`ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\Aditya Sethi\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk`

`path : existing path;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools`

now when I am trying to add platform with `cordova platform add android` it fails

Error is :
$ cordova -d platform add android
cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
Checking if platform "android" passes minimum requirements...
Creating android project...
Running command: "C:\Users\Aditya Sethi.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\c
reate.bat" --cli "c:\Users\Aditya Sethi\Documents\Project\conference\platforms\a
ndroid" com.phonegap.helloworld HelloWorld
'C:\Users\Aditya' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Command finished with error code 1: C:\Users\Aditya Sethi.cordova\lib\android\c
ordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat --cli,c:\Users\Aditya Sethi\Documents\Project\confer
ence\platforms\android,com.phonegap.helloworld,HelloWorld
Error: C:\Users\Aditya Sethi.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat:
Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (c:\Users\Aditya Sethi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mod
ules\cordova\src\superspawn.js:126:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a whitespace related issue. Try not to have whitespace's in your path eg. `Aditya<space>Sethi` or use shortened DOS names like `ADITYA~1`

eg. your env variable can be:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\ADITYA~1\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk
```

Comment: $ cordova platform add android
Creating android project...
'C:\Users\Aditya' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: C:\Users\Aditya Sethi\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat:
Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (c:\Users\Aditya Sethi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mod
ules\cordova\src\superspawn.js:126:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)

Comment: Just tried what you suggested.. I changed ANDROID_HOME : C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk

Comment: It didnt, check my first comment.. that is the error what I got in console

Comment: Check all your configuration's. You still have a reference of `C:\Users\Aditya<space>Sethi\...` somewhere as the error points out.

Comment: I went to computer settings, changes the enviornment variable as you suggested. Is there anything else that I have to take care of? Because I verified twice and the system variables doent have space now.

Comment: Try to move your project out of `Documents`, it too might be a reason. `c:\Users\Aditya Sethi\Documents\Project\conference\platforms\a ndroid`